# Wordpress updater conflict

Tags: wordpress-version, wordpress.org

I have created a theme named "landscape" and it's still on version 1.0
but I am getting notified in wordpress updates dashboad that there is a new version 1.0.3
If I click on update the free theme on wordpress theme directory overwrite my own theme.
I don't understand this conflict ..
I renamed the theme in style.css but I am still encountering the same issue.
Please help.I don't want to rename the folder name of the theme.
is there a way to prevent the updates from wordpress.org api?

Thank You

Comment: Same things happens for plugins too. Changing theme name should fix the issue though. Probably cache/transient.

Comment: I think this shouldnt work like this.. fortunately I had a backup for my theme, because the wordpress.org overwrote all my files with its own.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no — there is no way to completely and reliably prevent your public plugin/theme coming up as duplicate if WP org thinks that it is.

There are limited things you can do while it's active (intercept update requests, unfortunately there isn't even canonical up–to–date tutorial on that), but that goes out of the window when it's *not* active, since code is not running.

Comment: Thank you @Rast for your answer. so what I understand now that if someone creates is a theme named "themename123" and someone else creates another theme with the same name, wordpress.org will detect new updates for the  first theme even that it's still on version 1.0 .. just for the reason that the second theme is being updated? .. I am encountering this issue that the theme submitted in wordpress.org overwrote my theme when I launched the update. I believe this is a conflict.